# How do I assign ticks to be equal to a different key value from the same object from the one on which the axis is based on in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

So basically I have an array of objects like this one:

```
{
  "year": 1753,
  "month": 1,
  "monthStr": "January",
  "variance": -1.366
}
```

Currently my yAxis is based on the numeric value of the month ("month": 1), but I would like the actual yAxis' ticks to be the string values of the corresponding objects that are stored under "monthStr" key  than those numbers that are stored under "month" key.

Ex., instead of having [1, 2, 3, 4, etc.] on the yAxis I would like to have ["January", "February", "March", "April", etc.] showing in its logical order.

```
const yScale = d3.scaleTime()
.domain([d3.min(dataset, yValue), d3.max(dataset, yValue)])
.range([0, innerHeight]);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(d => d3.timeFormat('%M')( new Date(0).setMonth(d) ));
```

I tried to pass different options in the `.tickFormat()`, but can't make it work as I would like with those corresponding strings. Could you please help me to find a solution here?

```js
function addMonthStrings (dataset) {
  for (let i=0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
    let newPropName = 'monthStr';
    switch (dataset[i]['month']) {
      case 1:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'January';
        break;
      case 2:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'February';
        break;
      case 3:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'March';
        break;
      case 4:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'April';
        break;
      case 5:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'May';
        break;
      case 6:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'June';
        break;
      case 7:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'July';
        break;
      case 8:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'August';
        break;
      case 9:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'September';
        break;
      case 10:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'October';
        break;
      case 11:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'November';
        break;
      case 12:
        dataset[i][newPropName] = 'December';
        break;
    };
  };
};

const render = (baseTemperature, dataset) => {
  const width = 960;
  const height = 500;
  
  const xValue = d => d['year'];
  const yValue = d => d['month'];
  const monthStr = d => d['monthStr'];
  const variance = d => Math.round10(d['variance'], -1);
  const currTemp = d => Math.round10(baseTemperature - d['variance'], -1);
  
  const margin = { top: 40, right: 60, bottom: 40, left: 60 };
  const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
  const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  
  const titleText = 'Monthly Global Land-Surface Temperature';
  const titleXAxisPos = innerWidth / 2;
  const titleYAxisPos = 10;
  
  const subtitleText = `${d3.min(dataset, xValue)} - ${d3.max(dataset, xValue)}: base temperature ${baseTemperature}℃`;
  const subtitleYAxisPos = titleYAxisPos + 22;
  
  // Initiate a svg canvas
  const svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .style('height', height)
    .style('width', width)
  
  // Initiate a heat map
  const heatmap = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);
  
  // Establish a scale
  const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([d3.min(dataset, xValue), d3.max(dataset, xValue)])
    .range([0, innerWidth]);
  
  const yScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([d3.min(dataset, yValue), d3.max(dataset, yValue)])
    .range([0, innerHeight]);
  
  // Create axes
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d => d3.timeFormat('%Y')( new Date(0).setFullYear(d) ));
  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(d => d3.timeFormat('%M')( new Date(0).setMonth(d) ));
  
  heatmap.append('g')
       .attr('id', 'x-axis')
       .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${innerHeight})`)
       .call(xAxis);
    
  heatmap.append('g')
    .attr('id', 'y-axis')
    .call(yAxis);
  
  const titleSection = heatmap.append('g')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    
  titleSection.append('text')
    .attr('id', 'title')
    .attr('x',  titleXAxisPos)
    .attr('y', titleYAxisPos)
    .style('font-size', '1.5em')
    .style('font-weight', 'bold')
    .text(titleText);
    
  titleSection.append('text')
    .attr('id', 'subtitle')
    .attr('x', titleXAxisPos)
    .attr('y', subtitleYAxisPos)
    .style('font-size', '1.2em')
    .text(subtitleText);
  
  
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/global-temperature.json', true);
  request.send();
  request.onload = function () {
    let json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    let baseTemperature = json.baseTemperature;
    let dataset = json.monthlyVariance;
    addMonthStrings(dataset);
    render(baseTemperature, dataset);
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
  font-family: monospace;
}

svg {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to generate a function converting Month number into full labels, `d3-time-format` does it for you..

The specifier for full Month name in `d3.timeFormat` is `%B` (source: [d3-time-format documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format).

```
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
                .tickFormat(d => d3.timeFormat('%B')( new Date(0).setMonth(d-1) ));
```

Because Months in javascript dates go between 0 and 11, we need to deduct 1 from `d`, which goes between 1 and 12.

The snippet below illustrates the solution.

Few other modifications were made in order to get the chart visible in firefox:

- set svg width and height as `attr` rather than `style`
- remove hard-coded CSS positioning.

```js
const render = (baseTemperature, dataset) => {
  const width = 960;
  const height = 500;
  
  const xValue = d => d['year'];
  const yValue = d => d['month'];
  const variance = d => Math.round10(d['variance'], -1);
  const currTemp = d => Math.round10(baseTemperature - d['variance'], -1);
  
  const margin = { top: 40, right: 60, bottom: 40, left: 60 };
  const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
  const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  
  const titleText = 'Monthly Global Land-Surface Temperature';
  const titleXAxisPos = innerWidth / 2;
  const titleYAxisPos = 10;
  
  const subtitleText = `${d3.min(dataset, xValue)} - ${d3.max(dataset, xValue)}: base temperature ${baseTemperature}℃`;
  const subtitleYAxisPos = titleYAxisPos + 22;
  
  // Initiate a svg canvas
  const svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)
  
  // Initiate a heat map
  const heatmap = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);
  
  // Establish a scale
  const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([d3.min(dataset, xValue), d3.max(dataset, xValue)])
    .range([0, innerWidth]);
  
  const yScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([d3.min(dataset, yValue), d3.max(dataset, yValue)])
    .range([0, innerHeight]);
  
  // Create axes
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d => d3.timeFormat('%Y')( new Date(0).setFullYear(d) ));
  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(d => d3.timeFormat('%B')( new Date(0).setMonth(d-1) ));
  
  heatmap.append('g')
       .attr('id', 'x-axis')
       .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${innerHeight})`)
       .call(xAxis);
    
  heatmap.append('g')
    .attr('id', 'y-axis')
    .call(yAxis);
  
  const titleSection = heatmap.append('g')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    
  titleSection.append('text')
    .attr('id', 'title')
    .attr('x',  titleXAxisPos)
    .attr('y', titleYAxisPos)
    .style('font-size', '1.5em')
    .style('font-weight', 'bold')
    .text(titleText);
    
  titleSection.append('text')
    .attr('id', 'subtitle')
    .attr('x', titleXAxisPos)
    .attr('y', subtitleYAxisPos)
    .style('font-size', '1.2em')
    .text(subtitleText);
  
  
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/global-temperature.json', true);
  request.send();
  request.onload = function () {
    let json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    let baseTemperature = json.baseTemperature;
    let dataset = json.monthlyVariance;
    render(baseTemperature, dataset);
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
  font-family: monospace;
}

svg {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```